# jQuery's ajax function does not work in Android PhoneGap application

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, ajax, cordova

I want to access open API through ajax in mobile application, its work fine in iphone but does not working in Android phonegap application:

`returning error->"error message-null,typeerror-Result of expression 'data'[null] is not an object and error status-parsererror"`

Is there any browser setting need to follow.

I want to call the web service in android-phonegap application:

```
$.ajax({  
   url:'stringURL',  
   beforeSend: function(x) {      
     x.setRequestHeader('Authorization','username/pwd');  
   },  
   dataType:"xml",  
   contentType:'application/xml',  
   timeout:10000,  
   type:'POST',  
   success:function(data) {  
     alert(data);  
   },  
   error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown) {     
     alert("Error status :"+textStatus);  
     alert("Error type :"+errorThrown);  
     alert("Error message :"+XMLHttpRequest.responseXML);  
   }
});
```

Comment: Which browser and what does your code look like?

Comment: i update post with the coding part and as browser considering, in phone, default browser is safari and in android, default browser is opera mini

Comment: @Mayur - Thanks for updating your code, as for the browser: you shouldn't *assume* the defaults, or force others to...everyone I know with an android phone uses a non-default browser.

Comment: @Nick the above code working fine in iphone(phone-gap) application but just not working in android app,for specially my android application, i can not say to the people 'used non-default one, never'

Comment: Which version of Phonegap code are you running (the latest via cloning off github, a tagged version from the site, etc.), and which device and/or simulator are you seeing this issue?
I personally don't use jQuery on mobile as jQuery is huge and has a lot of cross-browser code that is unnecessary in a mobile context. Huge JS files in PhoneGap can lead to slow performance.

Comment: Try to add a :

data:""

what happens then?

Comment: @fil maj for the record, jQuery is not huge... not even close in a mobile context loaded with PhoneGap that has resources bundled.  Under 100kb will not affect the performance even slightly, the Sizzle engine will definitely be slower than native query methods, but that is not influenced by the filesize.

Comment: @tbranyen I disagree. 70 kb of minified JS is a big chunk of code for mobile browsers. I can tell you from the numerous mobile projects I've worked on, from prototyping something from scratch to optimizing existing applications, removing jQuery makes a huge difference.

Comment: Could it be that the request is cross domain and jQuery ajax fails? I usually use JSON with a callback function to deal with that.  I only did that once with PhoneGap and it worked.

Comment: That's because you're not giving us the information we need to help you. Try updating to the latest version of jQuery and PhoneGap, if the problem still exists, post a link to a live version your app so there is something to test on.

Comment: Just looked at this: did you really say Opera Mini?

Comment: @Mayur, don't forget that you can [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) to your question to motivate people to give good answers. You should probably edit your question to specify _which_ browsers on _which_ platforms fail, and address @Matthew's concern about cross domain requests _before_ posting the bounty, save everyone the time to read all these comments.

Comment: Can you provide info on what's coming back over the line? e.g. Response HTTP headers & content. This might give some clues.

Comment: Any chance of this problem is a phonegap bug? EDIT: BTW, does it fail on other Android devices?

Comment: Seems there isn't enough info to diagnose the problem.  If anyone has a guess, please post it.  I would like to give the bounty to someone.  Guesses are fair game!

Comment: I am doing Research on it, still hard luck is on!. If any one has did successful ajax call in Android-phonegap app, please provide some hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that there is a parse error on the data fetched. You want the XMLHttpRequest to parse XML data, so the fetched URL has to return valid XML. There are several possible reasons why that works on one but fails on another platform:

-The browser request headers may be different, resulting in a different server answer. Some servers may give HTTP 200 status answers with some error message in case of problems, which doesn't parse to valid XML.

-The returned XML may be problematic and parses well on the iPhone due to quirks in the browser there but fail on another WebKit version / variant the Android uses.

-The fetched data is damaged due to other request headers, provider, proxy or other effects. For example some proxys only handle HTTP/1.0 requests, and bad behaving servers serve HTTP/1.1 with chunked encoding every time, so the XML will be damaged by the chunk headers.

For debugging purposes you can change the request to a text request and show the fetched data, or even save it to the devices SD card if possible in your application. You can then verify it has arrived intact and is in fact valid XML.

Comment: I changed the request to text and still ajax function returning same error as I mention in the question. If you did it successfully in Android-phonegap app, please provide right javascript in your answer. waiting for your right answer.

Comment: kinda strange.. I currently have no similiar phonegap project for checking, sorry. Maybe you could try an ordinary XMLHttpRequest object like phonegap would do in its inside by yourself, fetch your servers data with it and check the results or if it fails too.