# How to parse xml from server to  in our html page for phonegap application

Tags: html, xml, cordova

I am a new in webdevelopment and i want to parse xml from webserver not from local server how is it possible .I tried lots of googled.Please  help me .I have to parse this url "http://twitter.com/statuses/public_timeline.xml"

Comment: What is your technology stack?

Comment: Are you trying to do that in an ASP.Net web application ?!

Comment: i am using simple html application not  asp.net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use JQuery (http://jquery.com/) plugin in HTML page as entry in a script tag, called jquery's ajax() function to hit the url and u can use jquery's parseXML() and find() function to parse xml data 
like this-

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
function onBodyLoad(){
$.ajax({  
    url:'http://twitter.com/statuses/public_timeline.xml',  
    dataType:"xml",  
    contentType:'application/xml',  
    timeout:10000,  
    type:'POST',  
    success:function(data) {  

    alert(data);
    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( data ),
    $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
    $title = $xml.find( "title" );

    /* append "RSS Title" to #someElement */
    $( "#someElement" ).append( $title.text() );

    /* change the title to "XML Title" */
    $title.text( "XML Title" );

    /* append "XML Title" to #anotherElement */
    $( "#anotherElement" ).append( $title.text() );

    },  
    error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown) {     
      alert("Error status :"+textStatus);  
      alert("Error type :"+errorThrown);  
      alert("Error message :"+XMLHttpRequest.responseXML);  
    }});
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="onBodyLoad()">
<p id="someElement"></p>
<p id="anotherElement"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sir thanks for your answer .But i want to parse xml for phonegpap application for iphone and android. how is it possible ?pls help

Comment: Hi Sandeep check the latest post in anwser.

Comment: but sir ajax does not support in android then how can we use ajax in phonegap application for android phone?

Comment: then it will bring to same question that earlier i had - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708282/jquerys-ajax-function-does-not-work-in-android-phonegap-application

Answer (score -2):

This is called syndication feed

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/How-to-create-a-syndication-feed-for-your-website.aspx

you can take help from above url, and can use ASP.NET wrapper for Twitter API as well